# Reviewed Firebase Docs, still have a couple of questions about choosing Firestore and Cloud Functions locations

Tags: firebase, server, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

So most of my users should be based in India, which is why I'm considering choosing Asia-South1 as my Firestore location. However, this warning is presented to me:

Note for Cloud Functions customers: Deploying a function to this location is not yet available. If your function and Cloud Firestore are in different locations, then you could potentially experience increased latency and billing costs.

Now the documentation tells me that asia-east2 is the closest region for functions.

I have the following questions in this regard:

Does "Note to Cloud Functions customers" mean Google Cloud Functions or Firebase Cloud Functions? ---I only wish to use Firebase Cloud Functions in my project.

If I choose asia-east2 as the location for my Cloud Firestore when most of my users are in asia-south1, does that mean extra costs for me? Since I will be saving on egress costs which are incurred if your storage location differs from cloud functions location, I want to be able to do a cost-benefit analysis here.

For a simple application that does not execute too many or too heavy cloud functions, would you rather suggest:

a. Setting 2 different locations - Setting my user population location as the Cloud Firestore location and the closest Cloud functions available location as the location for Firebase Cloud Functions

OR

B. Setting both locations to the nearest Cloud functions available location instead of my user's location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Cloud Functions on either platform (they are near-identical, but with different configurations), you are charged based on the number of times those functions are invoked as well as the resource cost (memory and CPU) to execute those functions (when you exceed any [free-tier limits](https://firebase.google.com/pricing)).

By setting your Firestore location to `asia-south1` and accessing it from Cloud Functions in `asia-east2`, you will be charged (as applicable) for the round-trip time between those two datacentre locations - even if the Cloud Function is just waiting for a response.

Ultimately, what works best for you depends entirely on what you are attempting to do. Here are some broad categories to point you in the right direction:

**If your application is cost-sensitive rather than time-sensitive**, colocate the Functions and Firestore deployments in `asia-east2`.

**If your application is time-sensitive on the client side and Cloud Functions usage is very low**, you may split the two across the two datacentres - but prepare to be charged for round-trip times. You can reduce the number of network hops by making use of batched writes, [field transforms](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue), and using transactions sparingly whilst also expecting delays & retries.

**If your application is time-sensitive on the client side but Cloud Functions usage is high enough to exceed free-usage limits**, colocate the Functions and Cloud Firestore deployments in `asia-east2`.

#### Notes:

- Depending entirely on data structure and what your Cloud Functions are doing, it may be beneficial to shard your data and maintain two Cloud Firestore instances - one in `asia-east2` for use by Cloud Functions-focused operations and the other in `asia-south1` for client-focussed data that is rarely used by Cloud Functions.
- Firebase also provides a [cost calculator](https://firebase.google.com/pricing#blaze-plan-calculator) that can be used to estimate your month-to-month costs. Of particular importance may be the *Networking (egress)* cost as it is unclear if datacentre-to-datecentre costs will increase this.
- You can also submit a [Feature Request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features) to add `asia-south1` as a supported Cloud Functions region and they can pass it on the relevant teams.